# Find and extract all email address from a text string using c#

Tags: list, email

Is there a way to extract all email addresses from a plain text using C# .

For example this string:

```
[id=4068;name=mrgar@yahoo.com]
[id=4078;name=mrrame@gmail.com]
```

should return

```
mrrame@gmail.com, mrgar@yahoo.com
```

I have tried the following code without success.

Please, can you help me?

```
protected void btnFinal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    object obj = jsSer.DeserializeObject(hidJsonHolder.Value);
    Movie[] listMovie = jsSer.ConvertToType<Movie[]>(obj);
    foreach (Movie p in listMovie)
    {
        txta.Text += p.ToString();
        const string MatchEmailPattern =
       @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
       + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
         + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
       + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(p.ToString());
        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Response.Write(p.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think basically you already had a correct `regular expression` to extract all email address from a text.

However, the problem is that you don't use it correctly.

The correct steps are as follow:

Use `regular express (Regex)` to match the text.

For each match result in `MatchCollection`, fetch the value from the match result.

To make the `Regular expression` clearer, I put all `Regex` method into on extra method which you could call separately for email extracting.

All of codes are written based on your original codes.

More details, you could refer to below codes.

**.aspx Page:**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>This is Page</h1>
            <asp:Button ID="btnFinal" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btnFinal_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="displayLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void btnFinal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string exampleTxt = @"[id=4068;name=mrgar@yahoo.com][id=4078;name=mrrame@gmail.com]";
    string[] emails = identifyEmailAddress(exampleTxt);
    foreach (string s in emails)
    {
        displayLabel.Text += s + "<br />";
    }
}

private string[] identifyEmailAddress(string txt)
{    
    const string MatchEmailPattern = @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
    Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(txt);
    int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
    string[] result = new string[noOfMatches];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        result[i++] = match.Value.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

**[image: Demo:]**